# If EM waves are made of oscillating electric and magnetic fields, how come photons have no charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I just recently learned that electromagnetic waves are made of oscillating electric and magnetic fields, and I have a question. In the standard model, photons are described as having zero charge, and if they are made from electric and magnetic fields, why are they not classified as charged? Is it because the crests and the troughs of the waves are canceling out? or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Because *theoretically* you don't need to have a charge to create an electric field.

Comment: 1. Why *would* electric and magnetic fields be classified as charged? Electric and magnetic fields classically just pass *through* each other (superposition prinicple of ED), they don't interact. 2. Look at e.g. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2796/50583) for a QED reason why chargeless photon can still distinguish between charges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric and magnetic fields themselves are totally uncharged. They are *always* described as totally uncharged things. They can either be described as two uncharged fields (when treated in the more traditional formulation) or as aspects of a unified electromagnetic field. In both descriptions the field(s) interact with charged things without being charged themselves.

The interaction works both ways so (for example) the electric field can move a charged thing around and the charged thing will cause a change in the field near it but the field itself is never charged.