Can you redirect an electromagnetic interaction with a mirror?
Sorry if this question is a bit naive, but, if photons mediate electromagnetic interactions, can you deflect those interactions with a set of mirrors or gravitational objects? And would this result in the attracted object going in the "wrong" direction?
EDIT: It might be impossible in practice to do something like this, but I think the question would really be whether the direction of virtual photons encodes the direction of the attraction/repulsion they mediate.

Isn't this basically what a Faraday cage does?

The method of image charges somewhat resembles what you are thinking

Assuming I understand your question correctly:
You are referring to the attractive electromagnetic (EM) force between a positive proton and a negative electron, which is mediated by virtual photons. The same force causes electrons to repel. Your idea is that perhaps those virtual photons could be manipulated by a mirror or other methods (such as gravitation) to alter the attraction or repulsion. Let’s examine the issues.
First, the virtual photons which mediate the EM field are relatively short range. Most of the effect occurs on a distance on the order of an atom or molecule, although there is some residual effect at longer distance (such as magnetism). In principle, these virtual particles must adhere to the rules of gravitation already, although this point ultimately depends on whether gravity itself is a quantum force. But keep in mind that photons do not actually go directly from a proton to an electron or vice versa in forming an attraction. It is a field effect from a large number of small interactions. There is no one photon to manipulate in the first place.
It should be clear that you won’t be able to manipulate the basic attraction within a molecule by inserting matter (such as a mirror) between a proton in the nucleus and a bound electron. The scale is wrong. A mirror is itself formed from a large number of molecules and itself a relative giant.
It should also be noted that proton/electron attraction is a very complex process. Among other things, the model explains why an electron does not simply fly into the nucleus. That won’t be obvious from a classical perspective.
So the answer is: No, you cannot use optical devices such as mirrors or lenses to reverse the EM force.

What about the gravitational option? And do you mean to say that virtual photons don't travel directly from one particle to the other?

@Flamethrower Gravity is so weak compared to the EM force that it be ignored, even if virtual photons are affected by it. You can’t vary gravity enough to see any effect. Virtual particles are created in pairs and usually annihilate very quickly. They cause a field effect that results in what we call the EM force. This description is very simplified, there are entire books about the details. So there really are no photons traveling from a proton to an electron in the normal sense.

Well, of course, we would be speaking of something like a micro-black hole.

How exactly are you going to create a “micro” black hole that is smaller than an atomic radius, influences photon path, but doesn’t suck the electrons out of the atom? Man-made black holes currently don’t exist. But you can get an idea of the issues in this Scientific American piece:  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/has-anyone-created-a-black-hole-on-earth/#:~:text=In%20fact%2C%20the%20possibility%20of,massive%20than%20our%20sun%20dies.

(+1) Could you elaborate "EM field are relatively short range, most of the effect occurs on a distance on the order of an atom or molecule" please? Suppose 2 electrons are stationary 1 meter from each other, will they remain stationary for a long time at this distance, since the electromagnetic force of a single electron has decayed too much by 1 meter to have any accelerative effect on another electron at this distance?

All practical limitations aside, I guess my ultimate question was "does the direction of photons encode the direction of the attraction/repulsion they carry?"

@Flamethrower Although photons do carry momentum, I would say the answer is no. A photon is its own anti particle and does not otherwise have any kind of observable that would relate to charge directly.

Then how do particles receive the information of where they need to go?

@Flamethrower As I mention, the quantum explanation of charge attraction and repulsion is complex and outside the scope of your reasonable question. I might suggest this SE post as a way to get better insight, and it includes some additional references. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57874/do-protons-exchange-photons-with-electrons

A mirror is loosely a plane of free electrons. An EM wave hits the electrons and causes them to vibrate. Vibrating charges radiate. The generated EM wave isn't the original wave redirected. It is a new wave that adds to the original. The sum of the two cancels the original wave - the total wave behind the mirror is $0$. The only thing left is the reflected wave.
