# Understanding attractive Feynman diagram

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, coulombs-law, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

I’m curious about the origins of the positive/negative charge and why there might be the two, and only the two, electric charges. I saw a great example just now which I think was referencing a Feynman diagram explaining the phenomenon of repulsion and attraction:

Repulsion: two particles as people in boats passing a ball back and forth (photons) - this passing is pushing the boats backwards from each other due to their momentum from each pass

Attraction: two particles as people in boats throwing a boomerang back and forth (photons) - this curved momentum of the photon when it reaches the opposing boat pushes the boats together.

My question is: what might be causing this allegorical “curve” in the photons so that their reception is causing a force of **attraction?** And if these analogies are correct, wouldn’t that mean that a massive particle actually has no charge except for its relation to photon exchanges with other particles?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132654/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323612/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675203/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/593481/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79958/2451