# How do particles attract?

Tags: electrostatics, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

Particles of the same charge repel one another by "throwing" a virtual photon back and forth. Because the momentum of the virtual photon gets absorbed by the particles, they push each other away.

If this is true, how does particles of different charges attract each other? They are "throwing" virtual photons at each other, but then why do they attract?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79958/2451