How can the attraction of opposite electric charges be explained by the exchange of virtual photons?
Sometimes, the electric force between two electrically charged particles is explained by the analogy of two freely floating astronauts that start throwing a ball towards each other. In this analogy, momentum is transferred from the astronaut to the ball which causes the astronaut to move in the opposite direction than the ball. Similarly, the astronaut who catches the ball picks up that momentum and therefore also moves away from the other astronaut.
The same argument is then made for the repulsion of two alike electric charges: they exchange virtual photons which carry momentum and transfer it from one charge onto the other causing them to move away from each other. This makes sense until one considers opposite charges which attract each other. But the mechanism of exchanging virtual photons is the same and since each photon carries momentum which must be compensated by the emitting particle, how can the attraction of electric charges be explained by the exchange of virtual photons?

It's because you're pushing the analogy much further than it can go. Interactions in quantum field theory are just more subtle than bouncing a classical ball back and forth.

Zee has an analogy where, in an attractive interaction, the virtual particle is like a matchmaker who goes between people, bringing them closer together. But at this point we're just making up stories that have absolutely no resemblance to the underlying math. From that perspective, your question is like asking: "A real snake can't eat its own tail, so how it is possible to implement loops in Python?"

The Feynman diagrams do not show a physical process. They are a diagrammatic representation of an integral that makes up a term in an infinite series. You cannot interpret the tree level diagram as one particle throwing a virtual particle to the other.

Does this answer your question? Photons acting as carriers of both attractive and repulsive forces

Science does not really know how they attract/repel ... it is s a very fundamental force .... we may never know.

The problematic part in fact starts when thinking of a photon as of something that has a defined position in each instant. The assertion that the momentum that is transmitted coincides with the photon motion, starting from one particle and then going to the other one, will then break down the analogy when describing attraction.
If you are aware that it's only an analogy, you can push this analogy a bit by having the astronauts pull on a rope that's conveniently lying in space just in the two astronauts line. Alternatively, replace the ball by a boomerang.

Another very relevant question + answers can be fpund here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230113/

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79958/2451 and links therein.

A virtual photon is just a Fourier component of the Coulomb potential. A Feynman diagram is a graphical notation of a perturbation term, not a picture of a physical process. It is easy to forget this.
